# Loading Bitmap in C++ with Big-Endian issues

Tags: c++, bitmap, endianness

I am currently reading in a Bitmap in Visual Studio with the following code:

```
    unsigned char* imageIO::readBMP(char* filename) {
    FILE* f = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        printf("%s \n", "File Not Loaded");
    }

    unsigned char info[54];
    fread(info, sizeof(unsigned char), 54, f); //read the 54-byte header

    //extract image height and width from header
    imageWidth = *(int*)&info[18];
    imageHeight = *(int*)&info[22];

    imageBytes = 3;
    size = imageWidth * imageHeight * imageBytes;

    unsigned char* readData = new unsigned char[size]; //allocate 3 byte per pixel
    fread(readData, sizeof(unsigned char), size, f); //read the rest of the data at once
    fclose(f);

    return readData;
}
```

However I am trying to get this code working on a PowerPC and it pulls the wrong Width and Height from the bitmap header. I think this is to do with Little Endian (Regular PC) and Big Endian (PowerPC).

How should I get the bitmap to be read on a Big Endian machine?

Can I just flip the Little Endian data?

Comment: To partially answer your question, yes it's an [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) issue. You need to know the structure of the data you read and how to do byte-swapping to be able to solve it.

Comment: `imageWidth = *(int*)&info[18];` violates strict aliasing and therefore is undefined behavior.  If there's an alignment restriction on `int`, such code can fail, likely with `SIGBUS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this (it should work on either big- or little-endian architectures):

```
unsigned int getIntLE(const unsigned char *p) {
#if LITTLE_ENDIAN
    return *(unsigned int *)p;
#else
    return ((unsigned int)p[3] << 24) | 
           ((unsigned int)p[2] << 16) | 
           ((unsigned int)p[1] << 8) | 
           p[0];
#endif
}

// ...

imageWidth = getIntLE(&info[18]);
imageHeight = getIntLE(&info[22]);
```

Note that you will need to define `LITTLE_ENDIAN` or use something that's predefined by Visual Studio. I don't have a Windows development environment handy to know what's used there.

Comment: I'll try this, it looks good! As for defining LITTLE_ENDIAN, I'm not sure what to define it as. I guess I could read the first few bytes of the header file and the order of them will determine little or big endianess?

Comment: No, that constant would be defined for the machine it's running on. The file format won't change, but the machine where you're building the code should have this (or similar) defined somewhere.

Comment: If the data is known to be big-endian, just use `ntohl()`.  See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/htons.3.html

Comment: Are `ntohl()` and friends available on the Windows platform? I thought they were POSIX-only, but it's been a long time since I've done development on Windows.

Comment: @MikeHarris Since Windows 8.1 or Server 2012:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: ntohl() looks promising, however it only takes a u_long value and the bitmap data is an array of unsigned chars. Apologies if I'm being stupid.

Comment: @MikeHarris Thanks very much! Your code fixed my issues! Well I know for certain at the moment that the PowerPC I'm running it on is Big-Endian, so I have left out the `#if LITTLE_ENDIAN` section, but it works! I'll now try and change the code so that it will check for Little Endian or Big Endian.